# I don't know why I get this result when I use reduce consecutively in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I found something strange while testing this and that.

```js
function func1(data) {
    return data.reduce((prev, x) => {
        prev.push(x);
        return prev}, []);
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

func1(arr).reduce((x) => {
    console.log(x)
    return x;
})
```

output:

```
1
1
1
1
```

My expectation is that it returns an array, so I wanted to print the values ​​for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in the next reduce, but it failed. Why did you get this result?

Comment: You've omitted the second paramter to `reduce`, so the first item of the array is used as the accumulator `x`. You only ever return that value.

Comment: In the second call `func1(arr).reduce`, you are not passing explicit `ac`, and first value is iteratively logged and returned as `ac`

Comment: Replace the second reduce with `forEach`

Comment: Its just your output. func1 works nicely: 
console.log(func1(arr)) returns VM178:1 (5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Your first `.reduce()` seems to make a shallow copy of the array, which you can also achieve by simply using `[...arr]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce operation reduces inputs with the operation supplied in your function starting with an initial value (or the first element if no initial value supplied) Each iteration takes the previous response and next array element to evaluate the same function.

Since your function does not have an initial element it takes your first element "1" to initialize. And your function does not evaluate anything but returns the element you first supplied. Therefore you always print your first element as the result.

You can check [these examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#examples) to better understand reduce operation.